# SQL Server JOIN query with GROUP BY

Tags: php, sql, join, group-by

I have this query, which I want to retrieve the results, grouping just by `Banksphere.servicio_id`, without doing any `sum(XXX)` because each `Banksphere.servicio_id` has it's own values separated by `hora_id`, `peticion_id` and `valor`...

So the result must be something like this...

```
[servicio_id 1]
(hora_id 1) (hora_id 2) (hora_id 3)   ... 
(peticion_id 1) (peticion_id 2)    ...
(media 1) (media 1) ...    
(valor 1) (valor 1) ...    
...
[servicio_id 2]
(hora_id 1)    
(peticion_id 1) (peticion_id 2) ...    
(media 2)    
(valor 2)    
...
```

My query so far -

```
$sqlQuery = sqlsrv_query($conn, "
    SELECT
        Umbrales.minimo as media,
        uok.minimo as media_ok,
        Banksphere.id as valor_id,
        Umbrales.id as umbral_id,
        Banksphere.servicio_id,
        Banksphere.peticion_id,
        Banksphere.hora_id,
        Banksphere.valor
    FROM
        Banksphere
    LEFT JOIN
        Umbrales
    ON Banksphere.hora_id = Umbrales.hora_id 
    AND Banksphere.dia_id = Umbrales.dia_id 
    AND Banksphere.servicio_id = Umbrales.servicio_id
    AND Banksphere.entidad_id = Umbrales.entidad_id 
    AND Banksphere.peticion_id = Umbrales.peticion_id
    LEFT JOIN
        Umbrales uok
    ON Banksphere.hora_id = uok.hora_id 
    AND Banksphere.dia_id = uok.dia_id 
    AND Banksphere.servicio_id = uok.servicio_id
    AND Banksphere.entidad_id = uok.entidad_id 
    AND uok.peticion_id = 0
    WHERE
        Banksphere.entidad_id = '$entidad_id'
    AND
        Banksphere.reconocido = 0
    AND
        Banksphere.fecha = '$fecha'
    ORDER BY
        Banksphere.servicio_id ASC,
        Banksphere.hora_id DESC,
        Banksphere.peticion_id ASC
");
```

Comment: You want to Group; but the GROUP BY statement is missing?

Comment: I can't use GROUP BY because of the JOINS, already tried and it returns me an error because LEFT JOIN UMBRALES...

Comment: So what error?! You're very vague in what your issue is.

Answer (score 2):

The short story: use ORDER BY, not GROUP BY; use MySQL; or use PostgreSQL and pay close attention to your functional dependencies. (I'm not sure PostgreSQL will work in your case.)

If Banksphere.servicio_id is unique within your result set, use ORDER BY instead of using GROUP BY. If Banksphere.servicio_id is unique in this context, the result set using ORDER BY is determinate, but the result set using GROUP BY is not.

First, look at this simple table.

```
create table test (
  column_1 integer,
  column_2 integer,
  column_3 integer 
  );

insert into test values
(1, 2, 3),
(1, 4, 5),
(1, 6, 7),
(1, 8, 9);
```

Grouping by a column returns one row for each value in that column.

```
select column_1, column_2, column_3
from test
group by column_1
```

This query should return one row. The value in "column_1" will be 1, of course. What value will appear in "column_2" and "column_3"?

You can't tell. In fact, this query will give you a syntax error in any standards-compliant SQL dbms, because you haven't told it what to do with "column_2" and "column_3". In a compliant SQL dbms, "column_2" and "column_3" *must* either be part of the GROUP BY or be used in a aggregate function.

MySQL *will* execute that kind of query without error, but [returns indeterminate results](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-extensions.html).  "The server is free to choose any value from each group, so unless they are the same, the values chosen are indeterminate." MySQL calls this a feature. I call it "broken as designed"--*indeterminate* isn't a defensible feature in a SQL dbms.

Under slightly different conditions, a compliant dbms *can* return nonaggregated columns without them being explicitly included in the GROUP BY. PostgreSQL, for example, will let you [GROUP BY the primary key](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-select.html).

> When GROUP BY is present, it is not valid for the SELECT list
>   expressions to refer to ungrouped columns except within aggregate
>   functions or **if the ungrouped column is functionally dependent on the
>   grouped columns**, since there would otherwise be more than one possible
>   value to return for an ungrouped column. A functional dependency
>   exists if the grouped columns (or a subset thereof) are the primary
>   key of the table containing the ungrouped column. [emphasis added]

So in PostgreSQL 9.1+, you can query a table that has a primary key like this.

```
create table test (
  column_1 integer,
  column_2 integer,
  column_3 integer,
  column_4 integer,
  primary key (column_1, column_2)
  );

insert into test values
(1, 1, 2, 3),
(1, 2, 4, 5),
(1, 3, 6, 7),
(1, 4, 8, 9);

select column_1, column_2, column_3, column_4
from test
group by column_1, column_2
order by column_1, column_2

COLUMN_1  COLUMN_2  COLUMN_3  COLUMN_4
--
1         1         2         3
1         2         4         5
1         3         6         7
1         4         8         9
```

The columns "column_3" and "column_4" aren't part of the GROUP BY, and they're not part of any aggregate function. But there's a functional dependency between the columns in the GROUP BY and the nonaggregated columns in the select list, so the result is determinate.

As far as I know, PostgreSQL is the only currently SQL dbms that implements this part of the SQL standard. (The standard goes further than PostgreSQL does.)